# ASP.NET Identity - what the difference between UserName and Id in IUser interface?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

We are working on an application which uses ASP.NET Identity (v 1.0). We defined an `User` class that implements the `IUser` interface. Our repository class `UserRepository` implements `IUserStore`.

Now when I call `UserManager.CreateAsync(user, password)` it calls `FindByNameAsync()` method of `UserRepository` to check (I guess) if this new user has an unique ID.

However I don't understand why it calls this method instead of `FindByIdAsync`?

I supposed that the `UserName` property on the `IUser` interface is something like person name (e.g. "John Smith") and `Id` is an internal unique identifier of an user.

From this default implementation I guess I was wrong.

The question is: why do we need these two properties (`Id` and `UserName`) on the `IUser` interface in this case? What the difference between them? Which of them is supposed to be an unique ID?

Comment: I highly suggest upgrading to Identity 2.x (the latest version).  They made a lot of things easier, and included a lot of functionality you'll want

Comment: We'll definitely do that. But the question remains the same.
Are Username and Id equal by their purpose and what is the reason to have both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ID's are typically numbers, although the default implementation of Identity uses Guid's.  Name is username, typically a handle or shortening of a full name.  Often times this is an email address, depends on how you set it up.

Id's are used as primary keys in your database.  Names are not.  The reason is that you might delete a user with a given username, and another use might come along and want to create an account with the same name.  But, you still need a way to identify that these are two different users for auditing and historical reasons.

When creating a user, how exactly would the code know the userid to look it up?  The username is the only thing it knows...

Answer (score 1):

They're both unique. Createasync calls findbyname as you're not going to know an Id for a user that you're going to create as it doesn't exist yet.

FindByID Exists as it's quicker to do a lookup on that after you've created a user.

Comment: It's probably not that much quicker, given that both are string types in Identity.

Comment: You can override the ID to be an Integer though.

Comment: Not in Identity 1 you can't.

Comment: Does Identity 1 create an Index on the username column? I know it does in Identity 2..